# Normed Linear Space - maximum norm vs. $||f||_1$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, inequality, normed-spaces

For $f$ in $C[a,b]$ define $$|| f ||_1 =\int_a^b |f|.$$ 
a. Show that this is a norm on $C[a,b]$.

b. Show that there is no number $c \geq0$ for which $$||f||_{max} \leq c ||f||_1 \ for \ all  \ f \ in  \ C[a,b]$$

c. Show there is a $c\geq 0$ for which $$||f||_1 \leq c||f||_{max}  \ for \ all  \ f  \ in  \ C[a,b]$$ (where $||f||_{max}=\max\limits_{x \in [a,b]} |f(x)|)$

I proved a. by showing all norm properties (the triangle inequality, positive homogeneity and nonnegativity). I also proved part b. by false assumption that leaded me to contradiction

Any help on part c.
Thanks

Comment: Integrate $|f(x)|\le \|f\|_\text{max}$ on $[a,b]$.

Comment: just to make sure i got it: $|f(x)| \leq \max\limits_{x \in [a,b]}|f(x)|=||f||_{max} \leq c||f||_{max}$ last inequality is true for any $c\geq 0$, now if i integrate i got $||f||_1 \leq c ||f||_{max}$ Correct?

Comment: If you integrate that, you got $(b-a) \|f\|_\text{max}$ on the right hand side, then set $c = b-a$.

Comment: @JohnMa Why is it true that on $[a,b]$ we have $|f(x)|\le$ max$(f(x))$?

Comment: We have $|f(x)|\le \max |f(x)|$. This is what we need. @johnny09

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It holds that $|f(x)| \leq \max_{x \in [a,b]} f(x):=||f||_{\max}, \forall x \in [a,b]$.

Thus:

$$||f||_1= \int_a^b |f(x)| dx \leq \int_a^b ||f||_{\max} dx= ||f||_{\max} \int_a^b 1 dx=(b-a) ||f||_{\max}$$